# Unicorn Sync button not visible

Tags: unicorn

Unicorn V4.1.1

Sitecore V9.3

For one of my project Sync button is not showing on the /unicorn.aspx

Here is the unicorn.config.config which is there.

**Can anybody suggest what setting might be missing for sync button to appear? Also please note that sync button is appearing for other sites, just not for a particular one.**

```
<configuration name="TestSite 2016" description="Test Site 2016 serialized item paths.">
          <predicate type="Unicorn.Predicates.SerializationPresetPredicate, Unicorn" singleInstance="true">
            <exclude database="core" path="/sitecore" />
            <include name="c" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/TestSite 2016" />
            <include name="m" database="master" path="/sitecore/media library/TestSite 2016" />
            <include name="l" database="master" path="/sitecore/layout/Layouts/Layouts/TestSite 2016" />
            <include name="r" database="master" path="/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Renderings/TestSite 2016" />
            <include name="t" database="master" path="/sitecore/templates/Templates/TestSite 2016" />
            <include name="a" database="master" path="/sitecore/system/Aliases/TestSite 2016" />
            <include name="md" database="master" path="/sitecore/layout/Models/Models/TestSite 2016" />
            <include name="io" database="master" path="/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Insert Options/Rules/DuFR_Custom_InsertRules_1" />
            <include name="ps_audits" database="master" path="/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SPE/Reporting/Content Reports/Reports/Audits/TestSite 2016"/>
            <include name="pss" database="master" path="/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SPE/Maintenance/Task Management/Scripts/TestSite2016" />
            <include name="tsk" database="master" path="/sitecore/system/Tasks/Tasks/TestSite2016" />
          </predicate>
        </configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe there are some errors.. Can you share the screenshot or the error details (highlighted in orange background with white text), that is found in /unicorn.aspx?

Comment: @PaulsonMaclean, there is one in the top and also for this specific project.which one you are refreing to?

Comment: For the project that is missing the sync button..

Comment: what's `<exclude database="core" path="/sitecore" />` doing in the predicate?

Comment: But generally speaking; a predicate will refuse to sync if A) the root folder for the predicate is not present on disk. Often due to misconfiguration. Or B, the predicate relies on a root iterm in Sitecore that does not exist.